# jQuery easing plugIn, negative scrollTop, when reach top or bottom

Tags: jquery, html, css, easing

I made a simple one page website, and I have trouble with the easing plugin in, when moving from page one to page two, there is not enough space at the top for it to "anticipate" (animation term),  nor at the bottom moving up to page two.  please see demo for my code, thanks.

PLEASE SEE DEMO HERE http://jsfiddle.net/56vmztjn/
StackExchange's demo, is acting funny...

```js
jQuery.extend( jQuery.easing,
{
 def: 'easeInBack',
 swing: function (x, t, b, c, d) {
  //alert(jQuery.easing.default);
  return jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def](x, t, b, c, d);
 }, easeInBack: function (x, t, b, c, d, s) {
  if (s == undefined) s = 1.70158;
  return c*(t/=d)*t*((s+1)*t - s) + b;
 }
});
// utility
function onePage(el) {
 var windowWidth = $(window).width(),
  windowHeight = $(window).height(),
  next = el.next('.onePage'),
  prev = el.prev('.onePage');
 el.width(windowWidth);
 el.css({"min-height":windowHeight});
 
 el.find('.next').on('click', function() {
  goTo(el, next);
 });
 el.find('.prev').on('click', function() {
  goTo(el, prev);
 });
}
function goTo(start, end) {
 var ini = start.offset().top,
  destination = end.offset().top, 
  distance = Math.abs(ini - destination),
  speed = distance/1.5; 
 $('html body').animate({
  scrollTop : destination
 }, speed);
}
// on ready
$(document).ready(
 function() {
  $('.onePage').each(
   function(index, el) {
    onePage($(el));
   }
  );
 }
);
```

```css
body, html {
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
.onePage {
  padding: 2em;
}
.a {
    background:red;
}
.b {
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="onePage a">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="onePage b">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 2</h1>
</div>  
<div class="onePage a">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 3</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: the code snippet looks weird let me add it to jsfiddle.

Comment: You aren't asking a question and I am not sure what your intended goal is. Can you clarify?

Comment: as you can see in my code the animation "should" pull in the other direction before it push to the next section.  this work well in page2

Comment: but in page1 the PULL can't happen b/c it is at the top of the `HTML, BODY` same at page 3 when I want to travel up to page 2.

Comment: if you understand what I mean, please edit the question for me.

Comment: Ok that makes sense now. Not sure I will be able to help but I imagine if you make extra space to the top & bottom the scrollbar will allow the users to scroll into this empty space if they do not use your navigation. See here http://jsfiddle.net/56vmztjn/1/

Comment: thanks for the help, but the trouble is not the space, the example you provided the scrolling up won't happen at page 1 b/c, the scroll bar is still at the very top (animation is depended on the scroll),  appreciated.

Comment: So if you dont mind the extra space you can add a scrolltop that will load the page to the area of your choosing. See the JQuery here: http://jsfiddle.net/56vmztjn/3/

Comment: @crazymatt, thanks that is a work around as long the color match,  scroll bar might be a little bit ugly but i can compromise at this point.

Comment: Submitted my answer based on our conversation here.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the conversation in the comments if you want the first and last page to have the 'pull' animation work using the 'easing-in' plug-in to show that animation you would need your website to have the extra space at the top and bottom of the page.

HTML

```
<div class="extraspace"></div>
<div class="onePage a top">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 1</h1>
</div>
<div class="onePage b">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 2</h1>
</div>  
<div class="onePage a">
  <button class="next">next</button>
  <button class="prev">prev</button>
  <h1>page 3</h1>
</div>
<div class="extraspace"></div>
```

CSS, add this

```
.extraspace {
    height:50px;
}
```

Doing this adds extra height to the top and bottom of the page so the pull animation will work but on page load there is an extra space at the top so we will need to navigate the use to the correct area on page load. We can do this with JQuery:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: "50px"}, 1);
});
```

The only downside to this is the user can manually scroll into the extra space sections. Hope this helps.